# I am trying to understand how the process of calculating the mean for every channel of RGB image

Tags: python, mean, preprocessor

I am trying to preprocess an RGB image before sending it into my model. The shape of the image is (2560, 1440,3). For that I need to calculate the mean of every channel and substract them from corresponding channel pixels. I know that I can do it by:
np.mean(image_array, axis=(0, 1)).
However, I cannot understand the process how it is being done.
I am aware of how axes work individually (axis=0 for columns and axis = 1 for rows). How does the axis = (0,1) work in this situation?

And also how can I do the same thing for multiple images, say, train_data_shape = (1000, 256, 256, 3)?
I appreciate every feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens when you have an array X of shape (5, 3) and you execute np.mean(X, axis=0). You’ll get back an array of shape (1, 3) where the (0, i) element is the average of the 5 values in column i. You’re essentially ‘averaging out’ that first dimension. If you instead set axis=1, you’d get back an array of shape (5, 1) where the (i, 0) element is the average of the 3 values in row i - now, you’re averaging out that second dimension.

It works similarly when multiple axes are provided. Say X is of shape (5, 4, 2). Then, executing np.mean(X, axis=(0,1)) will return an array of shape (1, 2) where the (0, i) element is the average of the sub-array X[:, :, i] (of shape (5, 4)). We’re averaging out the first two dimensions.

To answer your second question: If you want to compute means on an image-by-image and channel-by-channel basis, use axis=(1,2). If you want to compute means over all of your images per channel, use axis=(0,1,2).